# Improving accuracy on multilabe segmentation problem with DeepLabV3+ and ResNet101

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I took the code from this page and made several modifications: https://keras.io/examples/vision/deeplabv3_plus/

One thing I did was add flipping left right augmentation to the dataset:

```
def image_augmentation(img):
    img = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(img)
    return img

def image_process(path, mask=False):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)

    if mask == True:
        img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=1)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 1])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size])
        img = image_augmentation(img) # <- This is where the augmentation is happening

    else:
        img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size])
        img = img / 127.5 - 1

    return img
```

Then I've changed the backend from ResNet50 to ResNet101 but did not alter the convolution block. I've decreased the learning rate from `0.01` to `0.001`.

This is the CIHP dataset and I'm basically using the entire dataset for training and not a subset. After 25 epochs, my accuracy is at best 0.76. I've tried other augmentation techniques, such as random cropping, flipping up and down, brightness, etc. but all of them yielded far worse performance.

What are other things I can do to improve the accuracy?

**Edit**

This is my training code:

```
loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True)

lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor = 0.1,patience = 5, min_lr=0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr), loss = loss, metrics=["accuracy"],)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = val_dataset, epochs = 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would opt for a learning rate scheduler, so that I do not hold the
   learning rate fixed during the entire training phase. You can opt for either a built-in `ReduceLROnPlateau()` or define your own scheduler.
2. Error analysis. In which situations does the network predict bad? Which are the classes that have poor performance? It makes sense to augment only the situations in which the network poorly performs, those augmented samples would be the ones that would help you most when trying to improve the performance of the network.
3. An increase in image size may help the network learn small objects better, if the GPU memory allows you this I would resort to this approach. Replace the `BatchNormalization()` with `GroupNormalization()` (see `tensorflow-addons`) as you may have to decrease the batch size for the training to work.
4. Loss functions. Plain `categorical-crossentropy` (if multi-class) or `binary-crossentropy` (if multi-label) may not work that well in case of imbalanced problems. You could potentially use Dice loss or IoU loss; even a combination of those losses with binary/categorical crossentropy.
5. Last but not least, switching to another backbone (a more powerful feature extractor) could yield an increase in your metrics.

For (1) and example could be:

```
    reduce_lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='min') 
    ...
    model.fit(....., callbacks = [reduce_lr_callback])
```

Comment: Hello Timbus. Check the edits. I tried to add the `ReduceLROnPlateau()` but it is throwing the `ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau object at 0x7f0b032bcd10>) with an unsupported type (<class 'keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau'>) to a Tensor` error. Also, I use SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy as my loss.

Comment: You are incorrectly passing the ReduceLROnPlateau() as a callback

Comment: reduce_lr_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1,
                                                              patience=3, verbose=1,
                                                              mode='min')                                                                                     Then in model.fit(....., callbacks = [reduce_lr_callback])

Comment: But you've ommitted the code for `model.compile()`

Comment: Because you don't specify in the compile the callbacks, that's why.

Comment: But I don't understand. So do you want me to omit  `model.compile()` as well? I am setting the optimizer, the learning rate and the accuracy metric in there..

Comment: "..." stand for adding the code on your own, I cannot add multiple lines of code in the comment section, I just explained how you can add the ReduceLROnPlateau which has nothing to do with model.compile()

Comment: Right but you do see that I am adding the learning rate within my `model.compile()`'s optimizer section. So how can I add the `ReduceLROnPlateau()` to that?